# start downloading file with ajax

Tags: php, ajax, .htaccess, download

I like to access my download.php with ajax, that way I can show a little downloadscreen in a div, **BUT**

I have this in my **htaccess** file, that basicly says deny outside access for all pages.
I forgot about it, while I was trying to access my download.php file

**with  window.location = urlnieuw**

Is there a workaround for this problem and still keep the download.php protected against direct access??

or just trigger a jquery event, when the link is clicked

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

**edit**
the htaccess does not prevent direct access to files

thanks in adv, Richard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you think your mod_rewrite rule will prevent access from remote? The given rule will just rewrite requests of any URL that cannot be mapped directly to an existing file or directory to the *index.php*. There are no restrictions on who can or cannot access.

Comment: I figured it out, I was causing it myself, I thought it was the htaccess. Next question is howto prevent direct access to files, includes. But I will search for that first, because I am not to familiar htaccess files.

Comment: You can test if a `.php` was requested: `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /[^?\ ]*\.php[/?\ ]`

Comment: thanks,I wasn´t expecting an answer anymore
I was looking all over the place

I try´d this also, but it was causing some strange neverending loop 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?domain/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|php|html|png)$ http://www.domain.nl/images/logo.gif [R,L]

does your rule not interfear with the index.php

Comment: can you let it affect only the include files in the include folder
I guess in your example I could replace THE REQUEST with the file name.
And multiple files are comma separate|questionmark|. Here go´s my keyboard again.

Comment: @Richard: You can use this rule to respond with a 404 on requests of `/include/…`: `RewriteRule ^include($|/) - [L,R=404]`

Comment: Got a big internal server error, when using the last rule. 
The sever says something wrong with the internal configuration?